# How to run bash script as long as video length?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, shell, scripting

How to run bash script as longs as video length?

I will set up a cron to start bash script at 7PM, and I want to keep it running for as long as video length. How to do It?

Example: 7PM bash scripts starts movie.avi, that Is 3minutes length. Bash script keeps running for 3minutes then shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wait`.

From linux man page:

> **wait, waitpid, waitid** - wait for process to change state
>
> All of these system calls are used to wait for state changes in  a 
>   child
>          of  the  calling  process,  and  obtain information about the child whose
>          state has changed.  A state change is considered to be: the child  termi‐
>          nated;  the  child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a
>          signal.  In the case of a terminated child, performing a wait allows  the
>          system  to  release the resources associated with the child; if a wait is
>          not performed, then the terminated child remains in a "zombie" state.

As an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/vlc --vlc_args &
wait 
echo "VLC has finished."
poweroff # you said: "then shuts down"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bash script to play the video and quit when the video ends, you can use the vlc option `--play-and-exit` like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
vlc --play-and-exit /path/to/video.mpg
```

This way vlc will automatically exit when the video stop at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're calling the video software from the script, but as long as the software closes after the movie is complete, you could just use `wait`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/video/software &
$PID=$!

wait $PID
echo "Movie complete!"
```